# Java equivalent for Oracle INSTR function

Tags: java

I need to write the Java equivalent for INSTR Oracle function.

Example in Oracle:

```
select INSTR('vivek Srinivasamoorthy','a',14) from DUAL
```

Output:`15`

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Isn't that what `String.indexOf()` does?

Comment: BTW Documentation of `INSTR(string, substring, position)`: "The INSTR functions search `string` for `substring`. ... returns an integer indicating the position of the first character of this substring. If no such substring is found, then the function returns zero. ... `position` is an nonzero integer indicating the character of string where Oracle Database begins the search ..."

Answer (score 0):

`String.indexOf()` is your friend. Keep in mind that in Oracle counting start at 1, in Java at 0 (zero), so result in Java for your Oracle example will be 14. For docu see at [Oracle DB server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) and [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-).

In your specific case you can test it with `System.out.println("is on index: " + "vivek Srinivasamoorthy".indexOf("a", 13));`

Answer (score -3):

```
getInstring(String input, String substr, int start, int occurence) {
char[] tempstring = input.substring(start).replaceAll(substr, "-").toCharArray();
        int occurindex = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempstring.length; i++) {
            if (":-".equals(":" + tempstring[i])) {
                occurindex++;
                counter = i;
            }
            if (occurindex == occurence) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return counter == 0 ? -1 : counter + start + 1;
    }
```

Comment: is there any reason not to use standard java library?

Comment: indexOf he can use but it give the first occurrence and he is indented to get nth occurrence. Well it doesnt mean you can not use indexOf but you also need other lines as only using indexOf will not suffice your need.

Comment: in [java docu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you can see that indexOf() has variants, you can pick appropriate one.

Comment: dont know which variant you are referring, all lead to first occurrence .

Comment: @Ladislav DANKO Any comment please on your above saying, I dont want readers to lead in another direction..

Comment: again, in [java docu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you have more than one varints of the indexOf() method. you can pick one that satisfy your needs. in the case in question, it should be [`String.idexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) variant.

Comment: try code `System.out.println("is on index: " + "vivek Srinivasamoorthy".indexOf("a", 13));`